# Reloading file often in Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, heap-memory, web-audio-api

I am grabing a rtmp stream video and recording a MP3 file in a server, using java (I can record it in my PC, as well). I need to load this file in Web Audio API, considering that is constantly being updated, and play it like real-time stream. So, I am reloading the file quite often as I need real-time stream.

Theses are my options/problems:

- I try to load the file using < audio > tag (which I have to load every second) (MediaElementAudioSourceNode), I can't play it because the file which I've store in the server is not seekable and when I use play(), I'm not able to play with a offset.
- I try to load the file server using buffers(XmlhRequest + decodeAudioData)(AudioBufferSource),  AudioContext.decodeAudioData causes heap to grow without bound.